# Back Filling Dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with 3 columns.  Something like this:

```
Data        Initial_Amount   Current
31-01-2018
28-02-2018
31-03-2018
30-04-2018  100              100
31-05-2018  100               90
30-06-2018  100               80
```

I would like to populate the prior rows with the Initial Amount as such:

```
Data        Initial_Amount   Current
31-01-2018  100              100
28-02-2018  100              100 
31-03-2018  100              100
30-04-2018  100              100
31-05-2018  100               90
30-06-2018  100               80
```

So find the:

- First non_empty row with Initial Amount populated
- use that to backfill the initial Amounts to the starting date
- If it is the first row and current is empty then copy Initial_Amount, else copy prior balance.

Regards,

Comment: Please, post the code that you tried to solve the problem to show your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with fill method `'bfill'` (uses next valid observation to fill gap) should do what you're looking for:

```
In [13]: df.fillna(method='bfill')

Out[13]: 
         Data  Initial_Amount  Current
0  31-01-2018           100.0    100.0
1  28-02-2018           100.0    100.0
2  31-03-2018           100.0    100.0
3  30-04-2018           100.0    100.0
4  31-05-2018           100.0     90.0
5  30-06-2018           100.0     80.0
```